# List Category Posts rewrite necessitates rewrite of customised templates

Tags: plugins, templates, support, plugin-list-category-post

I just upgraded [the List Category Posts plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/list-category-posts/) from .17 to .18.3, and it broke my customised template :(.

My setup: WP 3.0.4 multisite network enabled, local installation with MAMP, PHP 5.3.2.

LCP plugin installed automatically. Works fine with the default template. However, you've rewritten the code such that the template had to be rewritten also.

I've managed, with a bit of a struggle (not strong in PHP), to tweak the default template and save it as my own customised template, and now it's displaying as I want.

I think this needs to be pointed out in documentation accompanying the updates.

One feature you've added - which I really appreciate - is to allow access to templates either in the parent theme or child theme. Thank you, this is working very well, and the best solution to the problem of whenever we update Wordpress.

Now, if only I can get the thumbnail to display. :(

Comment: The upgrade stuffed my personalized template also. Bugger on a live site :( Im not a PHP nut, so gotta dive in again to try and make sense of it. The plugin is excellent (though I cant get thumbnails to work either) but a revised / simplified system would be SUPER! Thanks.

Comment: Any news on the thumbnail issue guys please?

Comment: Hi Drin, sorry, still haven't worked it out. Fernando, are you out there?

Comment: Great question!  I am suffering from the same issue where the latest WP upgrade killed the display of LCP.  Is there a fix to this?  Even an explanation, or examples of the 15 minute route would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for reporting on this issue. Regarding the template system, I once more updated it, thinking the new version is easier to the user. I know it still lacks a big rewrite to make it user-friendly. The underlying code is pretty much set to use any new idea for it.

I added some upgrade notices for version 0.17 and 0.18. I guess it wasn't clear enough. I don't know if this is the place to discuss this, since it's more of a question / answer site (sorry WP Answers if this is wrong), but what would you think of a system like this?

```
[catlist id=6]
  <h2>{post-title}</h2>
  <i>Date: {date}</i>
  <p class="excerpt">{excerpt}</p>
[/catlist]
```

That would be simpler to write and understand for users who don't know PHP.

Regarding the thumbnails, I've tested it several times and it is working for me. You should add a new question on this site, with all the info on your theme, WordPress installation and the functions.php code for thumbnails, see if we can get other user / developer figure out why the plugin is not displaying the thumbnail.

Comment: Fernando, now that I reread my question above, I'm sorry it seems negative. I think v .18.3 is significant improvement. It did take 15 minutes to revise my template. I only think documentation at the WordPress plugin page should alert other List Category Post users for possible need to revise their templates when they update. Adding TEMPLATEPATH and STYLESHEETPATH for path to template is very clever and works perfectly. Your suggestion above looks more easily accessible for editing style, more user friendly. Thank you for your continued support and updating of List Category Posts plugin!